# I'm trying to show the contents of a pdf in a popup or a window which gets trigger at the click of a button

Tags: extjs

I tried couple of things but none worked for me. Is there any way we

> could show the content in the window Below is the code for the ok
>   button and the popup/window containing the pdf path also:

```
  {
                                            xtype : 'olm-button',
                                            text : 'OK',
                                            disabled : !isCustomerPaymentAddAllowed,
                                            hidden : !this.ex84ADSModEnable,
                                            tooltip : reasonText,
                                            itemId : 'OkbuttonItemId',
                                            width : '39px',
                                            height : Dims.convertToPxWidth(0, 2)-9,
                                            margin : '15 6 0 10',
                                            padding : '1 0 0 0',
                                            style:'font-size:100px;background-color: #666666; background-image: none;',
                                             handlerFn : function(sourceCmp, event, eOpts) {
                                                        me.updateOrCreateModel(me.getSaveMode());
                                                        me.eventToClearValues = 'OkbuttonItemId';
                                                        var paymentDtlModel = me.paymentModel;  
                                                        var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                                                                    title: 'PDF Content',
                                                                    width: 400,
                                                                    height: 700,
                                                                    modal: true,
                                                                    closeAction: 'hide',
                                                                    items: [{
                                                                        xtype: 'component',
                                                                        html: '<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/KKartikeya/Desktop/3744-ECard.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>',
                                                                    }]
                                                                });

                                                         win.show();

                                                    }
                                        },
```

> The result of the above code :

[image]>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your pdf example not found? or rejected by security concerns
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35cg)